# Program to simulate WC command in C

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program in C that simulates `wc` command in C.

This is what i have but it is returning always 0.

Can someone help me straight this out as I am not very familiar with C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int bytes = 0;
int words = 0;
int newLine = 0;
char buffer[1];
enum states { WHITESPACE, WORD };
int state = WHITESPACE;
 if ( argc !=2 )
 {
     printf( "Help: %s filename", argv[0]);
 }
 else{
     FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r");

   if(file == 0){
      printf("can not find :%s\n",argv[1]);
   }
   else{
            char *thefile = argv[1];
      char last = ' '; 
      while (read(thefile,buffer,1) ==1 )
      {
         bytes++;
         if ( buffer[0]== ' ' || buffer[0] == '\t'  )
         {
            state = WHITESPACE;
         }
         else if (buffer[0]=='\n')
         {
            newLine++;
            state = WHITESPACE;
         }
         else 
         {
            if ( state == WHITESPACE )
            {
               words++;
            }
            state = WORD;
         }
         last = buffer[0];
      }        
      printf("%d %d %d %s\n",newLine,words,bytes,thefile);        
   }
 } 

}
```

Comment: Maybe you need two variables: `enum states currentState, previousState;``if((currentState == WORD) && (previousState == WHITESPACE)) words++;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read(2)` accepts a filedescriptor as first argument, not a filename

```
  while (read(thefile,buffer,1) ==1 )
```

should be

```
  while (read(fileno(file),buffer,1) ==1 )
```

Btw: enabling and reading compiler warnings will point you to this kind of errors

EDIT:

mixing syscalls (`read(2)`) and high level functions (`fopen(3)`) is generally not a good idea; use either `fread(buffer, 1, 1, file)` or open the file with `open(2)`